# Why isn't JQuery datepicker value detected in code-behind of aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, sharepoint-2010

I have an application page (in a SharePoint application, if that is relevant) with a JQuery datepicker widget registered:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create JQuery calendar
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=TextBoxDato.ClientID %>').datepicker({ altField: "#<%=TextBoxDato.ClientID %>",
            altFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
        });

        $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['no']);
    });
</script>


<asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxDato" runat="server" />
<asp:Button ID="ButtonSubmit" runat="server" text="Do it" />
```

In the code-behind, on page load I add a small client-side script to validate the filename and then populate the text box with today's date:

```
// Add client-side script to check for existing file names
ButtonSubmit.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return checkFile()");

// Fill date box with today's date
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
```

...then, in the event handler for a click to ButtonSubmit, I try to read out the value that the user selected:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Parse(TextBoxDato.Text, new CultureInfo("fr-FR"));
```

My problem is that when clicking ButtonSubmit, the date that the user selected seems to be ignored in the code-behind - the value of 'now' is always today's date. When running a debugger, the checkFilename() JavaScript method is able to access the picked date, but the code-behind is not. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say

> In the code-behind, on page load I add a small client-side script to
>   validate the filename and then populate the text box with today's
>   date:

You are settings the `TextBox` value with the current date on page load. Put in some extra code on the `Page_Load` method

VB

```
If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
    '' assign the textbox value here
End If
```

c#

```
if (!Page.IsPosBack) {
     // assign the textbox value here
}
```

Otherwise everytime you click the button, the value will reset to the page load value

Comment: Wonderful, thanks. In retrospect that should have been obvious. I'm slightly newbish with ASP though.

Comment: We are ALL the same when it comes to learning and being new at something!

Answer (score 4):

Is the date TextBox read only? ASP.NET will ignore the new value if it is.

To get around this problem you can make the text box read only via JavaScript rather than via ASP.NET.

Comment: No, text box isn't read-only. Sorry for missing the text box control in the code, I have edited it now.

Comment: I had exactly this issue with a Jquery datepicker - I was replacing an Asp.Net calender control, and the original dev had readonly textboxes. Worked fine because the asp.net calender was doing postbacks to set value (I think)